# MOODLE Teacher Capability

Tags: moodle

I want a teacher capability to check the whether the login user is a teacher?

If teacher, I want a different Home Page i.e, my custom page

If student, a different page

Could anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is use the has_capabilty() function.  That is the way you should pose the question.  Does the user i am looking at have the capability to see this page.  Moodle is all about context and in one context the user may have a different capability than another.  Hence, to ask "if a user is a teacher" is the wrong question.

Example of implementation (using moodle 1.9)

```
 if(has_capability('block/my_history:userview', get_context_instance(CONTEXT_USER)) ){
    $this->content->footer = 'Manager View';
 }else{
    $this->content->footer = 'Non Manager View';
 }
```

See this forum discussion for more understanding http://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=70739

Notice the comments by Tim Hunt in this post http://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=126223

It takes a bit of learning, but it works well once you get your head around it.

Good luck